# ionic add platform android/ios : Cannot find module config-chain

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to upgrade my ionic version. so i just run

> npm install -g ionic cordova

seems successfully installed. but when i run

> ionic add platform android/ios

it shows ***Cannot find module config-chain***. so. i just follow the instructions and install the **config-chain** module. and another module just comes up :(. so and so..after about 10 module installed. it shows ***Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect...***.

oh~ anyone shows up to help me!?  thanks~~~

@suraj my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-bytediff": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-csso": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.8",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-task-listing": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.1.2",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0",
    "yargs": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
```

Comment: can you show your package.json in the question?

Comment: i've add my package.json. please have a look. thanks

Comment: does `npm cache clean` work?

Comment: sorry. it didn't work. but before i run ```npm cache clean```. i just finished ```npm update -g cordova ionic```

Comment: what is your npm version and what does `ionic info` give

Comment: npm version :```3.3.12```.  ionic info gives: ```Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.2.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002```

Comment: Try after upgrading npm `npm install -g npm@latest`. Yours is old

Comment: thanks. it did work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config-chain` is npm dependency, so chances are that **your npm installation is broken.**

Try to **reinstall** it, or use one of **npm** forks if npm itself isn't installable on your system for some reason

Refer [reinstall npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reinstall)

Comment: so it is `npm reinstall -g npm`?

Comment: npm install reinstall -g

Comment: @suraj if this solves your problem,plz accept the answer

Comment: I am not the one who posted the question

Comment: yep. i just can't install my npm. i'd like to try @Akshay Tilekar's way

Comment: yeah~ i've tried it. and it did worked for it. thanks